# How to install pgfplots in Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS?

Tags: pgfplots, installing, ubuntu

How to install `pgfplots` in Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS from Terminal?

I have the following:

```
a@a-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~$ pdflatex --version 
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0
Copyright 2009 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.46; using libpng 1.2.46
Compiled with zlib 1.2.3.4; using zlib 1.2.3.4
Compiled with poppler version 0.18.2

a@a-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~$
```

My texlive version has no problem.

```
a@a-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install texlive
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-29
  linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Which distribution are you using?  If you installed TeX Live, everything should be included.

Comment: I use pdflatex command to compile my tex file.

Comment: @user12290 No, Sean means do you use the Ubuntu 'packaged' version of TeX, a 'stand alone' TeX Live installation, or indeed something else. The first line of `pdflatex --version` will tell us.

Comment: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) and [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)